# How to convert xlsx into utf-8 csv in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8, xlsx

I have a xlsx file that I want to load and read in python into utf-8 csv.

I was able to convert it to csv but I'm not sure how to encoded to utf-8

code:

```
# Read and store content
# of an excel file
read_file = pd.read_excel ("path_filename.xlsx")

# Write the dataframe object
# into csv file
read_file.to_csv("path_filenam.csv",index = None,header=True)

# read csv file and convert
# into a dataframe object
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("path_filenam.csv"))

# show the dataframe
df
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the docs for `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`, simply pass this.

```py
read_file.to_csv('csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```